# Have I been hacked?

Tags: social-engineering

I noticed that my browser (Chrome) is blinking, as if someone is taking screenshots of pages I am browsing.

I am using Windows 8.1 box, with Kaspersky antivirus installed.

When I started Fiddler to see if there is any suspicious traffic, most of the traffic was normal, but I can see the following:

(1) [image]

(2) [image]

(3) [image]

(4) [image]

(5) [image]

I can see many records like those in the last screenshot but with different host names!

Now, have I been hacked? And what are the next steps to make sure no one is taking screenshots of my machine?

Comment: I'm seeing Microsoft and Google traffic. What are you seeing that is making you suspicious?

Comment: The 5th screenshot for example, contains strange hosts, and records like these ones repeated many times but with different hosts!

Comment: You mean the random strings as URLs? Chrome does that on purpose for DNS reasons. https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-discuss/F70-k_PGhEg

Comment: Cool! What about the 3rd screenshot: atdmt & liverail hosts?

Comment: atdmt and liverail are Facebook technologies

Comment: Great! Back to the blinking problem... What should I do next to make sure nothing is sent out of my machine?

Comment: It looks like you have done all the things you need to, and there is nothing out of the ordinary

Comment: If you want to know what's being sent/received from your machine, Wireshark is a much better option.  It will give you a better picture of what's going on.

Answer (score -1):

Your traffic looks normal from the excerpts. Normally, if you get hacked it will not be obvious from the traffic except under close analysis.

A blinking screen is probably because you loaded some page that had so much wacked out Javascript and CSS garbage that it is confused. It is probably time to restart the browser. Try using a script blocker to prevent sites from doing Javascript dumps on your client. If you let Javascript through globally you will get a lot of sketchy third-party scripts running on your machine. Usually they are just there to track you and deliver ads, but who knows, why risk it.

> What should I do next to make sure nothing is sent out of my machine?

Unplug the internet connection.